# How do I count repeated words in one cell using COUNTIF or other functions in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to use COUNTIF function to count how many times a word repeats in a cell.

[I use COUNTIF in the cell G7 but it only counts the word "Womans" once when it is show twice.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smwdS.png)

I want to be able to count how many times a word repeats in a cell. The word "Womans" is shown twice but it is only counted once. How can I fix this?

Comment: can you share your file structure so that we can suggest

Answer (score 2):

The COUNTIF function counts the number of cells in a range that meet the criteria given. For example, if I wanted to count the number of times the word "cats" appears in column A, I'd use `=COUNTIF(A:A, "cats")`

[image]

However, if we want to count the number of occurences of a string in another string, we can use this clever solution, `=(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2, B2, "")))/LEN(B2)`, with A2 being string being searched, and B2 being the string to search for.
[image]

Breaking it down, it figures out the length of the string, and the length of the string without the search string. Then, it figures out how many characters in the string were of the string to search, and divides the characters by the number of characters in the word, giving us the result.

In your case, you can use the formula `=(LEN(G7)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(G7, "womans", "")))/LEN("womans")`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution:

```
=LEN(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(?s)(W)omens|.","$1"))
```

This formula removes everything from cell A1 except the first letter of each occurrence of the word "Womens" then it takes the length of the resulting string.

Answer (score 1):

You could take it a bit further if you only want to count whole words e.g.

```
=countif(split(A1," ;:,.-"),"cat")
```

[image]